# Python object creation

Tags: python, class, object

I am pretty new to Python world and trying to learn it.

This is what I am trying to achieve: I want to create a Car class, its constructor checks for the input to set the object carName as the input. I try to do this by using the java logic but I seem to fail :)

```
class Car():
    carName = "" #how can I define a non assigned variable anyway like "String carName;" in java
    def __self__(self,input):
        self.carName = input

    def showName():
        print carName

a = Car("bmw")
a.showName()
```

Comment: What book are you using to teach yourself Python?  Where did you see code like this?  Did you read a web site?  If so, which one?

Comment: I think what you meant is __init__ instead of __self__.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

derived from object for [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)
use `__init__` to initialize the new instance, not `__self__`
`__main__` is [helpful too](http://docs.python.org/library/__main__.html).

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.carName = input

    def showName(self):
        print self.carName
def main():
    a = Car("bmw")
    a.showName()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't define a variable, and you use **init** and self.
Like this:

```
class Car(Object):
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.carName = input

    def showName(self):
        print self.carName

a = Car("bmw")
a.showName()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not correct!

```
class Car():
    carName = "" #how can I define a non assigned variable anyway like "String carName;" in java
    def __self__(self,input):
        self.carName = input
```

the first carName is a **class Variable** like static member in c++

the second carName (self.carName) is an **instance variable**,
if you want to set the **class variable** with the constructor you have to do it like this:

```
class Car():
    carName = "" #how can I define a non assigned variable anyway like "String carName;" in java
    def __self__(self,input):
        Car.carName = input
```