# __new__ and __init__ in Python

Tags: python, class

I am learning Python and so far I can tell the things below about `__new__` and `__init__`:

1. `__new__` is for object creation
2. `__init__` is for object initialization
3. `__new__` is invoked before `__init__` as `__new__` returns a new instance and `__init__` invoked afterwards to initialize inner state.
4. `__new__` is good for immutable object as they cannot be changed once they are assigned. So we can return new instance which has new state.
5. We can use `__new__` and `__init__` for both mutable object as its inner state can be changed.

But I have another questions now.

1. When I create a new instance such as `a = MyClass("hello","world")`, how these arguments are passed? I mean how I should structure the class using `__init__` and `__new__` as they are different and both accepts arbitrary arguments besides default first argument.
2. `self` keyword is in terms of name can be changed to something else? But I am wondering `cls` is in terms of name is subject to change to something else as it is just a parameter name?

I made a little experiments as such below:

```
>>> class MyClass(tuple):
    def __new__(tuple):
        return [1,2,3]
```

and I did below:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Albeit I said I want to return `tuple`, this code works fine and returned me `[1,2,3]`. I knew we were passing the first parameters as the type we wanted to receive once the `__new__` function is invoked. We are talking about `New` function right? I don't know other languages return type other than bound type?

And I did anther things as well:

```
>>> issubclass(MyClass,list)
False
>>> issubclass(MyClass,tuple)
True
>>> isinstance(a,MyClass)
False
>>> isinstance(a,tuple)
False
>>> isinstance(a,list)
True
```

I didn't do more experiment because the further wasn't bright and I decided to stop there and decided to ask StackOverflow.

The SO posts I read:

1. [Python object creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164309/python-object-creation)
2. [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> how I should structure the class using `__init__` and `__new__` as they are different and both accepts arbitrary arguments besides default first argument.

Only rarely will you have to worry about `__new__`. Usually, you'll just define `__init__` and let the default `__new__` pass the constructor arguments to it.

> `self` keyword is in terms of name can be changed to something else? But I am wondering `cls` is in terms of name is subject to change to something else as it is just a parameter name?

Both are just parameter names with no special meaning in the language. But their use is a *very* strong convention in the Python community; most Pythonistas will *never* change the names `self` and `cls` in these contexts and will be confused when someone else does.

Note that your use of `def __new__(tuple)` re-binds the name `tuple` inside the constructor function. When actually implementing `__new__`, you'll want to do it as

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # do allocation to get an object, say, obj
    return obj
```

> Albeit I said I want to return `tuple`, this code works fine and returned me `[1,2,3]`.

`MyClass()` will have the value that `__new__` returns. There's no implicit type checking in Python; it's the responsibility of the programmer to return the correct type ("we're all [consenting adults](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html) here"). Being able to return a different type than requested can be useful for implementing factories: you can return a subclass of the type requested.

This also explains the `issubclass`/`isinstance` behavior you observe: the subclass relationship follows from your use of `class MyClass(tuple)`, the `isinstance` reflects that you return the "wrong" type from `__new__`.

For reference, check out the [requirements for `__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) in the *Python Language Reference*.

**Edit**: ok, here's an example of potentially useful use of `__new__`. The class `Eel` keeps track of how many eels are alive in the process and refuses to allocate if this exceeds some maximum.

```
class Eel(object):
    MAX_EELS = 20
    n_eels = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.n_eels == cls.MAX_EELS:
            raise HovercraftFull()

        obj = super(Eel, cls).__new__(cls)
        cls.n_eels += 1
        return obj

    def __init__(self, voltage):
        self.voltage = voltage

    def __del__(self):
        type(self).n_eels -= 1

    def electric(self):
        """Is this an electric eel?"""
        return self.voltage > 0
```

Mind you, there are [smarter ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init/674345#674345) to accomplish this behavior.

Comment: But still, could you please give me a sample code with contains both `__new__` and `__init__` with arbitrary arguments passed.

Comment: @Braveyard: posted a toy example.

Comment: @larsmans as I understand, should we inherit from `object` if we want to use `__new__` and `__init__`? Or we just inherit it to use default `__new__` from the `object`?

Comment: @Braveyard: inherit from `object` to get `__new__`. In fact, it's a good idea to just always inherit from `object` unless you're writing backwards compat code for very old Python versions. In Python 3, old-style classes are gone and inheritance from `object` is implicit in class definitions.

Comment: @larsmans that makes sense right now :) inheritance from `object` is being implicit in 3.0. Since I used static languages more, inheritance from `object` was always implicit :)

Comment: @Braveyard: Python old-style classes are more like those in C++, where there's no global root class either. The oldest Python versions did not have classes at all, I believe, and new-style classes were introduced in an attempt to [unify *all* Python types](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) into a single hierarchy.

Comment: @Braveyard: correction; if I must believe the [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/History_of_Python), then Python had classes from its earliest releases. Sorry about that.

Comment: You shouldn't call `__init__` from `__new__`, Python will do that on its own if you return an instance of type `cls`.

Comment: I would add to this that the seemingly strange behaviour of being able to return something from `__new__` can (at least theoretically) be useful. I can imagine something like a `BalancedBinaryTree` class, that can be initialised from a list. It has subclasses for `LeafNode` and `EmptyTree`, and `__new__` returns one of those if the input list has 0 or 1 elements. Essentially it means you can implement factories without seeming to, and therefore you can change whether your classes use factories or direct instantiation without necessarily breaking your interface.

Comment: I think there is a bug, it should be `type(self).n_eels -= 1`, not `self.n_eels -= 1`.

Comment: I gave you +1 before I got to your eels example. Wish I could give another for `raise HovercraftFull`

Comment: I don't see how args and kwargs are passing from __new__ to __init__.

Comment: So, Basically, in short  `__new__` is a class method which gives direct access(read,write,modify and delete) to class attribute and `__init__` is a instance method which gives direct access(read,write,modify and delete) to instance attribute. Am I right? Please Clarify.

Comment: No answer for `When I create a new instance such as a = MyClass("hello","world"), how these arguments are passed?`?

Answer (score 2):

seems that nobody had cover how the arguments are handled through the instantiation

lets build a simple class that define **new** and **init**

```
censured = ["Cicciogamer"]

class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name in censured:
            print("you shouldn't do this")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
```

when you call a class object to get an instance, python implicity call

```
Foo.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so with the class above you get the (maybe) undesired double arguments passing:

```
foo = Foo("Cicciogamer")
>>> "you shouldn't do this"
foo.var
>>> "Cicciogamer"
```

To achieve the control on how these parameters behave ASFAIK you must override the **call** method of the CLASS OBJECT not instance

you can use metaclasses but it might be overkill

```
class MetaFoo:
    def __call__(cls, name, var):
        foo_object = cls.__new__(name)
        cls.__init__(foo_object, var)
        return foo_object

class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    ...


foo = Foo("Cicciogamer", 505)
>>> "you shouldn't do this"
foo.var
>>> 505
```

or i think you can achieve this with simply

```
class Foo:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, name, var):
        foo_object = cls.__new__(name)
        cls.__init__(foo_object, var)
        return foo_object

    __call__ = new
```

please let me notice if this could be achieved in a better way, or if i simply screwed up something

Answer (score -1):

Your question was something like,

> What is the difference between `__new__` and `__init__` in Python?

---

Suppose that we have a very simple class named `Rectangle`

```python
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width:float, height:float, /):
        self._width  = width
        self._hieght = height
        # implicitly return None
```

We instantiate the `Rectangle` class as follows:

```python
rocky_the_rectangle = Rectangle(10.01, 8.91)
```

The line of code above created a Rectangle having:

> `width = 10.01`
> `height = 8.91`

#### In order to construct the rectangle, the python interpreter did somthing like the following:

```python
rocky_the_rectangle = Rectangle.__new__(10.01, 8.91)
if isinstance(rocky_the_rectangle, Rectangle):
    Rectangle.__init__(rocky_the_rectangle, 10.01, 8.91)
```

Note that `__init__` can only return `None`

If you give `rocky_the_rectangle` to `__init__`, then `__init__` will do the following:

> 1. modify the original `rocky_the_rectangle`. It will ***not*** be a copy of rocky.
> 2. The output, or return value, from `__init__` will be `None`

---

The following is true about `__new__`:

> - `__new__` can return somthing other than a new instance of the Rectangle class.
> - `__new__` can read and write to attributes of the Rectangle class. The Rectangle class is not directly visible inside of `__init__`

The description above is most of it. However, if you are still confused, then keep reading.

---

Below, we have both an `__init__` method and a `__new__` method.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs, /):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, width:float, height:float, /):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
```

When we run this code, it can be difficult to see what is going on with our eyes.

There are different ways to debug code, but a quick and easy way is to add some print-statements which help us see the order in which functions get called, and what the input parameters were.

```python
def see_whats_going_on(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get the string version of the input arguments
    sargs = repr(str(arg))[] for arg in [self_or_cls, *args]

    # Example
    #     sargs = [
    #         "<__main__.Rectangle object at 0x7f7cf24be5d0>",
    #         "10.01",
    #         "8.91"
    #      ]    

    # Now, insert some commas and spaces in-between the args
    comma_seperated_values = ", ".join(sargs)
    csv = comma_seperated_values

    # Example
    #    csv is the following:
    #        "<__main__.Rectangle object at 0x7f7cf24be5d0>, 10.01, 8.91"

    # next, add some parentheses 
    stringed_function_inputs = "(" + csv + ")"

    return stringed_function_inputs
```

Let us insert calls to our little print-function into our code:

```python
class Rectangle():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        see_whats_going_on(cls, *args)        
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, width:float, height:float, /):
        args = (width, height)
        see_whats_going_on(cls, *args)
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    @classmethod
    def make_rectangle(cls, *args):
        new_instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
        if isinstance(new_instance, cls):
            cls.__init__(new_instance, *args)
        return new_instance
```

Now we can instantiate the `Rectangle` class as follows:

```
rocky_II = Rectangle.make_rectangle(10.01, 8.91)
```

`__init__` allows us to mutate the attributes of `self` in a modify-in-place manner.

However, `__init__` is not allowed to modify `self` by passing `self` into a function which returns a modified copy of `self`.

```python
# NOT ALLOWED INSIDE OF __init__
new_self = paint_it_blue(old_self)
```

The `__init__` method is unable to replace the `self` parameter with something new and different.

For example, people sometimes want to put a wrapper around the `self` parameter. You might want something like this:

```python
import functools
import sys

class decorator:

    def __new__(cls, kallable):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance = functools.update_wrapper(instance, kallable)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, kallable):
        self._kallable = kallable
        self._file     = sys.stdout

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__init__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [self, *args]) + ")", file=self._file)
        return self._kallable(*args, **kwargs)

@decorator
def pow(base:float, exp:int):
    """
         +------------------------------------------+
         |                EXAMPLES                  |
         +------------------------------------------+
         | BASE | EXPONENT |       OUTPUT           |
         +------+----------+------------------------+
         |    2 |        5 | 2^5      |          32 |
         |  2.5 |        7 | 2.5^7    | 610.3515625 |
         |   10 |        3 | 10^3     |        1000 |
         |  0.1 |        5 | 0.1^5    |     0.00001 |
         |    7 |        0 | 7^0      |           1 |
         +------+----------+----------+-------------+
    """
    base = float(base)
    # convert `exp` to string to avoid flooring, or truncating, floats
    exp  = int(str(exp))
    if exp > 0:
        return base * pow(base, exp-1)
    else: # exp == 2
        return 1

result1 = pow(2, 5)
result2 = pow(8.1, 0)
print("pow(2, 5) == "  , result1)
print("pow(8.1, 0) == ", result2)

print("What is the documentation string? The doc-string is... ", pow.__doc__)
```

It will not help to use `functools.update_wrapper` inside of `__init__`. If you try to write the following...

```python
class f:
    def __init__(outter, inner):
        # `outter` is usually named `self`, but you are...
        #     ... allowed to use other names for it.  
        outter = functools.update_wrapper(outter, inner)
```

... then outter will get ignored. You cannot replace the parameter named `self` with a different `self`

`__new__` allows us to replace `self` with a wrapper around `self`

```python
class decorator:

    def __new__(cls, kallable):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance = functools.update_wrapper(instance, kallable)
        return instance
```

Without using `functools.update_wrapper` inside of `__new__` the doc-string inside of the original callable will be wiped-out, ignored, not inherited, and/or shadowed.