# Learning how to write a Class and Object first time

Tags: python

So I am using the hardest way to learn python and I am on exercise 40, and below is the code that we are instructed to write into a file named ex40.py:

```
class Song(object):

    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                         With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Then to run it, I am doing: python ex40.py and I am receiving error:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:PythonsScripts$ python ex40.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 12, in <module>
    "So I'll stop right there"])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python object creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164309/python-object-creation)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Nope. This is just a typographical error. That question's asking something completely different.

Comment: first rule of debugging: look for errors in your code (hint: the TypeError tells you where to look)

Comment: fix the typos and you will have fixed your program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have *two* underscores around magic methods like `__init__`. That means this:

> ```
> def _init_(self, lyrics):
>     self.lyrics = lyrics
> ```

Should become this:

```
def __init__(self, lyrics):
    self.lyrics = lyrics
```

Comment: will do, once it allows me too =)

Answer (score 1):

The `_init_` function should be `__init__`.

I can also see, just from syntax highlighting, that the last string you use in the file is missing starting double-quotes

Comment: Thanks, i think i missed that quote when i copied it over. i do have it in the actual file